# Openlayers 3 A checkbox bound to a Vector layer for visibility is not doing anything

Tags: javascript, checkbox, openlayers-3

I'm trying to bind a checkbox to a vector layer for the 'visible' property and it's not working; easy points to whoever spots my typo :)

The thing is, this works for ol.layer.Tile, but not ol.layer.Vector, and only the visible checkbox doesn't work. 'opacity' works fine.

```
var list = document.getElementById('some-ul-element')
....

var li = document.createElement('li');
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.setAttribute('type','checkbox');
checkbox.setAttribute('checked',true);
li.appendChild(checkbox);
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(layer.get("title")));
li.appendChild(label);
var range = document.createElement('input');
range.setAttribute('type','range');
range.setAttribute('min','0');
range.setAttribute('max','1');            
range.setAttribute('step','0.01');
range.setAttribute('value','1');
li.appendChild(range);

new ol.dom.Input(range).bindTo('value',layer,'opacity');
new ol.dom.Input(checkbox).bindTo('checked',layer,'visible');

....
list.appendChild(li)
```

Comment: As a workaround, this small change works for me for both ol.layer.Vector layers and ol.layer.Tile layers..
[code]
    new ol.dom.Input(checkbox).bindTo('checked',layer,'opacity');
[/code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, the map I was using was declared with this option:

```
new ol.Map({ 
    ....
    renderer: ['dom','canvas','webgl'],
    ....
    });
```

This totally disabled 'setVisible', I couldn't even use 'layer.setVisible(false)' successfully.

Removing the entire "renderer" key value pair from the ol.Map options at instantiation fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me on http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/bind-input.html?mode=raw

```
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.setAttribute('type','checkbox');
new ol.dom.Input(checkbox).bindTo('checked',layer,'visible');

document.body.appendChild(checkbox);
```

Comment: Looking at this example, I notice that 'layer' refers to an 'ol.layer.Tile' layer, which I agree works with the checkbox bound to 'visible', but for some reason when I do the same thing with an 'ol.layer.Vector', it doesn't work for me.

Thank you for the response :)

Comment: I've just tried with a vector layer and it's works. Can you create a jsfiddle with a minimal example?

Comment: Sorry, no, but I haven't changed the code that I'm having an issue with from the question, and the openlayers version I'm using is 3.3.0.

I eventually will figure this out locally, and will update the question at that time, I just thought I'd ask here too

Comment: This issue is also present for me in both Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I'm guessing you added the JS Fiddle links to ol examples? Well whoever did, thanks. I've modified the one for that example and it seems to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/8mLuL92a/2/

I have no idea why my local version is not working, but it must be a local issue

Answer (score 1):

Did you had a look on this stackoverflow issue https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138364/layer-doesnt-turn-back-on-after-clicking-in-openlayers-3/139346#139346 There are also some alternative solutions to using the ol.dom.Input element.

Comment: Yes, that's a good example of how I'm trying to turn a layer on and off, with a check-box 'ol.dom.Input' binding.

Unfortunately it seems that the questioner there hasn't found an answer yet!